# Migrate media to external storage in Marshmallow

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, storage, 6.0-marshmallow

In versions of Android prior to Marshmallow 6.0, the Storage Manager (in Settings) had an option to move media to external storage.

Now, this option appears to to have disappeared. How can I still do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings -> Storage & USB" then tap on you SD card. Then tap on the "three-dot menu" at the top right corner and select "Migrate data".

Comment: I don't see that option under the three-dot menu.

Comment: Is your SD card formatted as adopted or portable?

Comment: It's formatted as portable.